# BigQuery to Elasticsearch Dataflow template ConnectionClosedException

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using the BigQuery to Elasticsearch Dataflow template to create an Elasticsearch index by transferring a BigQuery table. I am however getting a ConnectionClosedException at times.

At times (lately, every time), I get the following error in Dataflow (which does not make the Dataflow job to fail), and then not the expected number of documents are inserted in the Elasticsearch index.

> "org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException:
> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.elasticsearch.utils.ElasticsearchIO$Write$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:799)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:325)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:252)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1788)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2506)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.JavascriptTextTransformer$TransformTextViaJavascript$1.processElement(JavascriptTextTransformer.java:360)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.JavascriptTextTransformer$TransformTextViaJavascript$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:799)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:325)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:252)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1788)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2506)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.BigQueryConverters$TableRowToJsonFn.processElement(BigQueryConverters.java:152)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.BigQueryConverters$TableRowToJsonFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:799)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:325)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:252)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1788)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2214)
> at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn.processElement(Read.java:321)
> at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1096)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:656)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:651)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:325)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:252)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
> at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:537)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
> at
> org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed at
> org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:839)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:259)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:246)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.elasticsearch.utils.ElasticsearchIO$Write$WriteFn.flushBatch(ElasticsearchIO.java:1531)
> at
> com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.elasticsearch.utils.ElasticsearchIO$Write$WriteFn.processElement(ElasticsearchIO.java:1480)
> Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is
> closed at
> org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)"

I expect no connection error (as it not always happens) and all the documents to be inserted into the Elasticsearch index.

I am using the following Dataflow params:

- batchSize: 1000
- maxNumWorkers: 100

However, I have tried to tune the Dataflow job params (batchSize, batchSizeBytes, maxNumWorkers, workerMachineType, autoscalingAlgorithm) without success.

I have tried to use different versions of the template (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/dataflow-templates-europe-west3), and none solves the issue.

I have also tried transferring data from BigQuery to GCS in order to use the GCS to Elasticsearch template instead, but since my table contains REPEATED columns, I cannot export it as CSV, and the template expects CSVs as input, so it is not possible.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a transient/ temporary error that will resolve itself at a later time, since you mentioned this is happening intermittently. A couple of days after this post, an [incident was reported](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/U39RSGjaANJXtjHpRkdq) pertaining to networking issues on multiple Google Cloud products, yours might be one of the affected projects.

As the error suggests, ConenctionClosedExceptions, this is commonly triggered by network connectivity and resource exhaustion issues, be sure to monitor your logs for entries related to port availability or cluster health/ performance.

You can submit this to our [Issue tracking system and product feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in case the problem still persist today.